# Proxying Resource Manager in Google Dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I've followed Google instructions on this.

```
gcloud compute ssh  --zone=us-central1-b --ssh-flag="-D 8088" --ssh-flag="-N" --ssh-flag="-n" spark-test-m
```

followed by

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:1080" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE localhost" --user-data-dir=/tmp/
```

Navigate to https://spark-test-m:8088 and I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first SSH flag should be "-D 1080" per http://cloud.google.com/dataproc/cluster-web-interfaces

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. I'm blind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be two problems:

1. Since you passed `--ssh-flag="-D 8088"`, your local proxy port is actually 8088 instead of 1080, where you specified `--proxy-server="socks5://localhost:1080"` in your flags to Chrome.
2. It looks like you're trying to use an HTTPS url instead of HTTP.

Alternatively, sometimes your browser may have been configured to ignore the user-profile proxy settings in favor of some system ones. I'd first try to fix the proxy port, and then try both http://spark-test-m:8088 and also maybe http://spark-test-m:50070 to see if it's specific to the proxy connection or if maybe for some reason just the ResourceManager failed to come up.